# Django: Validating data with protection against race conditions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am writing a Django application for booking certain resources. My reservation model is more complicated, but think of a hotel room where you have a check-in and a check-out date. Clearly, each new reservation needs to be checked against conflicting data in the DB and there might be a race condition, if two conflicting reservations are entered simultaneously.
This is what I did:

```
    # q: unevaluated QuerySet that pulls conflicting reservations from DB
    # r: new reservation object
    with transaction.atomic():
        if not q.exists():  # no conflicts, if empty
            r.save()
```

My questions:

1. Is this correct, i.e. does it preserve data integrity?
2. Is there a native Django way (no raw SQL) to insert the integrity check
   right into the database? I assume this would be the best way to do it in order to prevent any possible way of invalid data entering the DB?
3. If there is no way to do it at database level, where do I tie this into Django so that I catch all or most ways to add new objects to the DB?

Comment: anything in transaction.atmoic block is an atomic transaction. In an atomic transaction your table is locked the query makes changes and then the table is unlocked again so no need to worry about race condition. Now data integrity is your problem. You have to put checks by yourself to see that your db does not break or does not raise any errors.

Comment: Can you show your models? Unless you're using some explicit locks in `q`, your current code is susceptible to race conditions. You need to lock a common resource used by both reservations to avoid race conditions. @ArpitSolanki None of the supported databases lock an entire table just because you execute a read query in a transaction.

Comment: @knbk locking depends upon the transactions as well like what query is being executed but atomic would certainly save you from race conditions

Comment: @ArpitSolanki `atomic` does not protect you from race conditions in any transaction isolation level except `SERIALIZABLE`, which is rare because of its effect on concurrency. The default level on most databases is `READ COMMITTED`, which by default only acquires _write_ locks. OP's code performs a read followed by a write, with no mechanism in place that prevents concurrent reads of the same data before the transaction is committed and the inserted data is available to other transactions.

Comment: @knbk after reading your comment and reviewing the Django documentation again it dawned on me that I might have been wrong: The code inside an atomic block does not protect against race conditions, but every database operation inside is rolled back, if an exception is raised. Correct? Then I could just optimistically save the new reservation then check for conflicts and raise an exception, if I find one. If both operations are executed within an atomic block, the database should be rolled back, right?

Comment: You're correct that raising an exception inside an atomic block will roll back the transaction, but that does not necessarily protect against race conditions. The default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level means that the new records in one transaction will not be visible to the other transaction until the first one is committed. So even when checking the records after inserting, a race condition may occur where the other transaction's insert is not visible even though that transaction passed the check for conflicts. To prevent all race conditions, you need to acquire a lock on a common resource.